# Unable to view the content of azure datalake storage via Synapse

Tags: azure-synapse

I have deployed Azure Synapse manually with Azure Portal.

I have and ADLS storage where I enabled only selected virtual networks and IP addresses.

Synapse is configured with managed private endpoint. With notebook I can interact with ADLS.
But with Synapse SAAS I see the following :

```
Unable to view this content
REQUEST_SEND_ERROR: Failed to send request to https://adlsdev.dfs.core.windows.net/bronze?recursive=false&directory=&resource=filesystem Learn more
```

Also pipelines that worked before raise an error when creating delta lake table ("null" path).

What can I do ?

Answer (score 0):

Unable to view this content:
REQUEST_SEND_ERROR: Failed to send request to https://adlsdev.dfs.core.windows.net/bronze?recursive=false&directory=&resource=filesystem. Learn more.

The error suggests you need to configure the storage private endpoint for your storage account.

Configure the storage private endpoint for vNet. Use the Azure portal to assign an Azure role for access to blob and queue data.

You can use the command below to check the connectivity after the storage private endpoint is configured:

```
"nslookup <storage-account-name>.dfs.core.windows.net"
```

When you run the above command, it should return a string like this: `"<storage-account-name>.privatelink.dfs.core.windows.net"`.

The steps to connect to workspace resources from a restricted network are as follows:

**Step 1:** Add network outbound security rules to the restricted network.

**Step 2:** Create private link hubs.

**Step 3:** Create a private endpoint for your Synapse Studio.

**Step 4:** Create private endpoints for your workspace resource.

**Step 5:** Create private endpoints for workspace linked storage.

**Step 6:** Allow URL through the firewall.

**References:** [Connect to workspace resources from a restricted network](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/security/how-to-connect-to-workspace-from-restricted-network).